# Which web mapping site can easily do location or direction searches by bookmark?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, user-interface, gis

Until a couple of days ago, one of my favorite Google Maps bookmarks had been the following (set up as a Chrome search engine with the keyword `gm`): `https://maps.google.com/maps?output=classic&q=%s`. This let me quickly display a map of a location or set of directions without having to fuss around with buttons and data entry. For example, I could type `gm 1600 pennsylvania ave, washington, dc` into the URL bar and immediately get a map of the White House. Or, `gm from:boston, ma to:cincinnati, oh to:los angeles, ca` to get directions from Boston to Cincinnati to Los Angeles. Or, `gm restaurants near:sandpoint, id` would give me a map of all restaurants in Sandpoint, Idaho. Fast, easy, direct, and to the point; nothing between me and the information I want.

My bookmark broke about a year ago when Google switched to their glitzy new mapping system (which I hate, [but](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2014/04/07/1290161/-The-new-Google-Maps-sucks) [that's](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/PYUD9zNuzXM) [just](http://geoawesomeness.com/4-things-hate-new-google-maps/) [me](https://medium.com/@andrew.burton/10-things-i-hate-about-new-google-maps-9dbb63683da9)). Inserting the `output=classic` term fixed that for a while, but now even that directs to the new mapping system. Even using the new Maps, typing text directions into the map search box fails: you have to click "Directions" and then fill in two different search fields to get what you want, and I can't even find a way to do multiple destinations. What was once a quick and easy search is now extended data entry. (It feels a lot like Mapquest used to be, requiring that users type each portion of an address into different fields, rather than being able to handle a complete address.)

Question: is there a way I can still do this with Google Maps? If not, is there some other service (Mapquest has come a long way) that will let me do this?

Edit: to be clear, there are (at least) three separate ways I could use that original shortcut:

1. Go to a specific location
2. Find all matching items near a specific location
3. Get directions from place A to place B, and perhaps to places C, D and E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add another searchengine for directions.

- key: `dir`(or what you want to)
- url: `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/%s`
- sample:(use slashes to separate the addresses)

  [`dir boston, ma/cincinnati, oh/los angeles, ca`](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Boston,+ma/Cincinnati,+oh/Los+Angeles,+ca)

Comment: Great! That's one of the three ways I used my original bookmark. I've clarified the other two; any ideas?

Comment: the other URLs are (1.)`https://www.google.com/maps/place/%s` and (2.)`https://www.google.com/maps/search/%s` , but it should be sufficient when you use `https://www.google.com/maps/search/%s` for 1.+2.